# How to call custom directive in scope function of another controller

Tags: angularjs, angular-directive, angular-controller

I am new to AngularJS. Can anyone tell me with example that how to call a custom directive in a scope function of another controller.

For example I have a controller with a function as follows:

```
angularApp.controller('sample_Ctrl', function ($scope, $http, $timeout, $rootScope, $location) {
     $scope.showReport = function(id) {
     };
});
```

I created a customDirective as follows:

```
var showModalDirective = function ($timeout) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        templateUrl: '/Partials/template1.html',
    };
};
angularApp.directive('showModal', showModalDirective);
```

So how to call this directive in the `showReport` function, and how can I pass id to template URL?

Comment: Your question is not clear. Can you add some context/example?

Comment: What do you mean by **call a directive**?

Comment: I added with an example,can you guys check now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't call `directive` in `controller`. It should be a `service`.

Or you can use directive in view:

**Directive**:

```
var showModalDirective = function ($timeout) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
           modalId: '='
        },
        templateUrl: '/Partials/template1.html',
    };
};

angularApp.directive('showModal', showModalDirective);
```

**Controller:**

```
angularApp.controller('sample_Ctrl', function ($scope, $http, $timeout, $rootScope, $location) {

  $scope.showModal = false;

  $scope.showReport = function(id) {
    $scope.showModal = true;
    $scope.modalId = id;
  };
});
```

**View**:

```
<div ng-if="showModal">
   <show-modal modal-id="modalId"></show-modal>
</div>
```

`showModal` directive is call when `showModal` variable is `true`.

Answer (score 0):

To use your directive first u need to create HTML element with same name as your directive then provide data for that directive from your controller. Suppose there is a div in your html page.

```
<div show-modal>  </div>
```

Then on this page your template1.html will call internally through directive and suppose there is some html element in template1.html like

```
code in your controller -
angularApp.controller('sample_Ctrl',function() {
     $scope.firstName= "My First Name"
})
```